# How to Loop and Read all the Required Attribute Values from XML using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, foreach

I have the following XML Data in a file "Test1.xml":

```xml
<TextValuess>
  <TextValues Name="Value1" Override="true" Type="String">
      <DEV>Source=DEV;Catalog=DEV_DMT;Integrated Security=SSPI;</DEV>
      <INT10>Source=LAB;Catalog=TST_INT10;Integrated Security=SSPI;</INT10>
      <INT>Source=LAB1;Catalog=TST_INT1;Integrated Security=SSPI;</INT>
      <INT2>Source=LAB10;Catalog=TST_INT12;Integrated Security=SSPI;</INT2>
  </TextValues>
  <TextValues Name="ENVIRONMENT" Override="true" Type="String">
      <DEV>DEV</DEV>
      <INT10>INT10</INT10>
      <INT>INT1</INT>
      <INT2>INT15</INT2>
  </TextValues>
</TextValuess>
```

I want to loop through all the attributes and retrieve the data using PowerShell by passing the parameter which I need to retrieve.

Eg: If I pass the Variable values as INT10 I need only below values something like this:

```
Name               Value
----               -----
Value1             LAB
Environment        INT10
```

I Was able to retrieve one of the element values using the below PowerShell commands.

```bsh
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content D:\Roshan\Test1.xml
$XmlDocument.TextValuess.TextValues[0].INT10
$XmlDocument.TextValuess.TextValues[1].INT10
```

But the XML tags might grow or reduce each and every time based on file. I need to loop through with the existing data and get the results.

I am not sure how to use `foreach` to read all the values in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most versatile way of selecting data from XML structures is [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx). In your case you'd do something like this:

```
$child = 'INT10'
$XmlDocument.SelectNodes("//TextValues[./${child}]") | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'Name'  = $_.Name
        'Value' = $_.$child
    }
} | Select-Object Name, Value
```

If you want partial information extracted from the child node you need to specify how that's done. For instance:

```
($_.$child -split ';')[0] -replace '^Source='
```

Comment: Can you also help me how can I assign Values to a Variable in the ForEach for Each read. Need Something like this    $child = 'INT10'
$XmlDocument.SelectNodes("//TextValues[./${child}]") | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        $Name  = $_.Name
        $Value = $_.$child
    }
} | Select-Object Name, Value

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pipe the `TextValues` to `Select-Object` and specify property names you want values of:

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content D:\Roshan\Test1.xml

$XmlDocument.TextValuess.TextValues | Select-Object Name, INT10
```

Comment: This is working to get the desired result. As the Ansger quirey is much convenient for my requirement, I have selected that as solution.